# How do I resolve the TypeError with databricks.proto for databricks-registry-webhooks?

Tags: python, typeerror, databricks, webhooks, mlflow

I am trying to create webhooks for [MLflow in Databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/en/_extras/notebooks/source/mlflow/mlflow-model-registry-webhooks-python-client-example.html). However, I am getting the following TypeError when importing `from databricks_registry_webhooks import RegistryWebhooksClient, JobSpec, HttpUrlSpec`

`TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool: duplicate file name databricks.proto`

It is the same issue I found on the community site [here](https://community.databricks.com/t5/community-discussions/error-loading-databricks-proto/td-p/45303).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that databricks-registry-webhooks has a databricks.proto file that collides with mlflow. Here is the fix:

```
%pip install databricks-registry-webhooks mlflow==2.2.2
```

You can test this is successful by running:

```
 from databricks_registry_webhooks import RegistryWebhooksClient, JobSpec, HttpUrlSpec
```